# JFXPanel in JFX Scenes inside JFrame causing FXComboBoxes not to "open"

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am working on an application written in Java which is designed using JavaFX.

Everything works properly except this one issue with FXComboBoxes.

As the title says, the scene is inside a JFrame using JFXPanel. I have buttons, comboboxes and tabs.

Everything works in this setup and even the ComboBoxes can be opened.

But as soon as I click on a button, which adds a JPanel to the tab using SwingNode, the ComboBoxes are no longer able to be opened.

To make it easier to explain my problem, i made a simple Java application to demonstrate it.

I am working on a Windows 8.1 64bit machine with Java 1.8u40.

Any help, tipp or solution is appreciated. I hope someone here can help me.

[image: application screenshot]

**Test:**

1. Try to open the Collection
2. Press the "Add Panel" Button
3. Try again to open the Collection

My example FXML file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="238.0" prefWidth="404.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="question.GUIController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="75.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Add Panel" fx:id="button_add" />
      <ComboBox layoutX="14.0" layoutY="19.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Choose">
        <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="Option 1" />
               <String fx:value="Option 2" />
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <TabPane layoutX="190.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Panel" fx:id="tab_panel" />
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

My Starter class:

```java
package question;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

public class Starter {
    private static URL fxmlPath = Starter.class.getResource("/question/main.fxml");
    private static JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        frame.setContentPane(fxPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
       });
    }

    protected static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel2) {
        Region region = null;

        try {
            region = FXMLLoader.load(fxmlPath);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (region != null) {
            Scene scene = new Scene(region);
            fxPanel.setScene(scene);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find or load fxml!");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my GUIController class:

```java
package question;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;

public class GUIController {

    @FXML private Button button_add;
    @FXML private Tab tab_panel;

    private AddListener addListener = new AddListener();

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        button_add.setOnAction(addListener);
    }

    private class AddListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
            JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel();
            tempPanel.setBackground(Color.red);

            final SwingNode graphSwingNode = new SwingNode();
            graphSwingNode.setContent(tempPanel);

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tab_panel.setContent(graphSwingNode);
                }
           });
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
18.1.2015 21:06: Using Threads now

Comment: Why mix JavaFX and Swing?

Comment: What do you mean "The collections can no longer be opened"? Do you mean that the combo box doesn't work?

Comment: if you move your mouse over the collections, you can see it changing colors (it detects the mouse) but if you press on it, the list doesn't get opened

Comment: You mean you can't select something from the combo box? ("Move your mouse over the collections" doesn't make any sense. A collection is a data structure, not a UI component.) I don't know if this is the cause of the behavior you are seeing or not, but you need to invoke the methods on the correct threads. Right now, everything is on the FX Application Thread. You need to update the Swing components on the AWT event dispatch thread. See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE).

Comment: the combobox doesn't get opened at all, thats what i ment with collections. the example above here has the same problem

Comment: @James_D i now have moved it to the correct threads but the problem remains

Comment: Can you update the question with the new code?